# In Perl what does "$@" mean?

Tags: perl

What does the $@ variable mean in Perl?

So what would:

```
if ($@) {
        return 0;
    }
```

be saying?

Thanks

Comment: See [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html), which covers all these odd [global] variables: "The variables $@ [..] contain information about different types of error conditions that may appear during execution of a Perl program."

Comment: @user2864740: I don't see what's "odd" about them

Comment: @Borodin Odd as in strange/unexpected (esp. of the beginner); odd as of irregular usage; odd as in a mismatched collection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Perldoc:

> The variables $@ , $! , $^E , and $? contain information about
>   different types of error conditions that may appear during execution
>   of a Perl program. The variables are shown ordered by the "distance"
>   between the subsystem which reported the error and the Perl
>   process...$@ is set if the string to be eval-ed did not compile (this
>   may happen if open or close were imported with bad prototypes), or if
>   Perl code executed during evaluation die()d. In these cases the value
>   of $@ is the compile error, or the argument to die

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html